# Quick Way to Find Info on a List of Updates

Tags: windows, windows-update

Let's say I want to debug an issue where a few client computers were impacted by a long list of updates that occurred in the last few months.  I run a `systeminfo | find /i "kb" > updatelist.log`. Now how can I find a way to *quickly* get a summary of the purpose for the updates.  There was a program that kind of did stuff like this for the pre-NT6.x operating systems, but this does not really work anymore.  Any useful websites that do this?

**UPDATE:** So maybe something like [Windows Update Downloader](http://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/) or the [MrJinje Update XML Tool](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/139692-update-list-xml-tool-w-source/) is kind of what I am looking for, but neither is really scriptable or queryable.

Answer (score 3):

Sysinternals [PSInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550) gives more information (product and title) than systeminfo does.  Try:

```
psinfo.exe /s | find /i "kb" > updatelist.log
```

Output:

```
[snip]...
Security Update for 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB969559)
Security Update for 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB976321)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (KB2416473) 1
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2518870) 1
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2539636) 1
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended (KB2416472) 1
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended (KB2487367) 1
...[snip]
```

Pasting the KB article number (eg KB969559) into the search window of "Help and Support" will give you a quick look-up of interesting patches.  Make sure Help and Support is set to search all microsoft products.

Comment: Also promising.  I have not played with PSInfo in a while, but I totally forgot.

Answer (score 1):

The MBSA tool from Microsoft is scriptable.  I'm not sure it will go back as far as you want however.  Might be worth a look.

Comment: Embarrassingly I was totally unaware of this tool.  I am checking it out now.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but what if I want to just query info about updates without referencing a specific machine, like picking a random one out of a hat. No tool seems to do this well.